# Word for not realizing that you don't have all the details?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been looking for a pair or words that mean that a person doesn't have all the details and doesn't realize that they do not, and its opposite counter part.

I was thinking the word "partialist" would cover the first thing, but this turned out to be a DSM-IV manual sexual disorder, despite it sounding right.

For example, "He was a partialist, he didn't know what he didn't know."

I thought that the opposite would be a "comprehensivalist" or someone who knows they have all the details.

Comment: All humans fall into the former category and none into the latter.  So this is like looking for a dedicated word for, say, a person who doesn't have a skeleton and doesn't realize that, and a person who knows they do have a skeleton. These are no useful concepts to have dedicated words for, and so we don't. Also, in case you're not noticing, you've got yourself a false dichotomy. You have two boolean variables, which should get you a total of four categories, not two. What about the people who don't have a skeleton and do realize it? What about those who do have one but don't know it?

Comment: I'd simply say they are *ill prepared*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Judging by the unwarranted derision heaped on Donald Rumsfeld for trying to [distinguish between "known unknowns" and "unknown unknowns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns), I'd say the average Joe has difficulty even grasping the *concepts* involved here, so the chances of us having special words for the different permutations seem remote.

Comment: The word for the first concept is *adolescent*. Mark Twain is reputed to have said *When I was a boy of 14, my father was so ignorant I could hardly stand to have the old man around. But when I got to be 21, I was astonished at how much the old man had learned in seven years.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh wow there's a 4th category!  And it's the one humans have the most trouble with.  unknown-knowns.  Things which we do not wish to acknowledge.

Comment: @leeand00: That surely implies a *fifth* category. By "things which we do not *wish* to acknowledge" I assume you mean there are questions we're "theoretically" capable of addressing, but which we suppress awareness of because we're worried we won't like the answer (though personally I think there's a certain "elegance" to **42** :). But Godel's Incompleteness Theorem tells us there are questions we only *think* we can answer (we don't really "know" the answer if we can't *prove* it; it's effectively a matter of blind faith).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was referring to this statement when I said a fourth category "Psychoanalytic philosopher Slavoj Žižek says that beyond these three categories there is a fourth, the unknown known,"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective "[sophomoric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophomoric)" comes to mind to describe the first category.  It means "conceited and overconfident of knowledge but poorly informed and immature."

Answer (score 0):

The concept can be summed up as "ignorant of one's own ignorance."  I think the word "ignoramus" is the one that serves, but its meaning has morphed in common usage to something more of a general insult than that specific meaning.